# How do I calculate the encrypted messages for the text?

Tags: rsa

Alice would like to communicate with Bob using RSA procedures. She thinks of two numbers $p = 3$, $q = 13$, and calculates $n = p · q = 39$.

Note: Only RSA trapdoor function can be used.

Bob would like to send a locked message to Alice $(A = 1, B = 2, ..., Z = 26)$ and sends each of them as separate message per letter. How to calculate encrypted message for $D$   $A$  $D$ ?

Can someone give me tip how to do it?

Comment: Since we don’t tend to act as a task-solving service, I hope you don’t mind me asking: [What have you tried? And where exactly did you get stuck while trying?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not asking someone to do everything just to give me begining tip.

Comment: Tip: Pick a public exponent and apply the RSA function letter-by-letter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know public exponent e for starters. Also the letters need to be encoded or it would literally be impossible to encrypt A as it is with RSA because any exponent to 1 is still 1, and thus no mod truncation.